# How do we use EditorTemplates in Razor Class Library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I've recently added a RCL (Razor Class Library) to our existing MVC ASP.NET 6 (core) web application.

While trying out using views, components and razor pages of the RCL I noticed my `[UIHint]` attributes weren't working.

So far I cannot get a view to render with the correct `[UIHint]` for a property. Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the path `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` to my RCL it started working!

FYI the attribute I used: `[UIHint("MultiSelect")]`
The path I created: `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MultiSelect.cshtml`